# 15.10 won't upgrade to 16.04 due to unsupported packages

Tags: 16.04, 15.10, do-release-upgrade

I've been trying to upgrade my 15.10 installation to 16.04, but it says that it cannot upgrade due to unsupported packages, and I cannot find any of the packages that are conflicting to the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do a "package upgrade". I would recommen to make a "fresh install". Download [the ISO-image](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you/?version=16.04&architecture=amd64), burn it to a DVD, reboot from the burned DVD and follow the installation programme. NOTE: PLEASE MAKE A BACKUB BEFORE INSTALLING, OTHERWISE YOU WHILL LOOSE YOUR DATA!

Comment: Well, you see, that's exactly what I was trying to avoid doing.